add items in listview control from another class
I'm trying to add items in my listview control calling from another class.
I have a form with a listview control and some buttons. When I click on one of the buttons, a usercontrol appears with buttons (addButtons.cs).
///making the buttons on the usercontrol
internal class AddButton
{

   ublic void New(UserControl user, String text, int Location_X, int Location_Y, String stringPath, string price)
    {
       System.Windows.Forms.Button button = new  System.Windows.Forms.Button
        {
            Text = text,

            ............
            Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(stringPath)
        };

        //when the button is clicked
        button.Click += BTNclick;
        user.Controls.Add(button);
        user.CreateControl();

       // button.Click += new System.EventHandler(OnClick);
    }

    public void BTNclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
         System.Windows.Forms.Button clickedbtn = sender as System.Windows.Forms.Button;

         //frmHoofd is my Form
        frmHoofd frmHoofd = new frmHoofd();

        string mail= clickedbtn.Text;
        string price= clickedbtn.Name;
        string count= "1";

        string[] array = { mail, count, price};
        frmHoofd.UpdatingListView(array);

    }


My main form where the listview control is.
namespace KassaSystem1._1
{
    // public delegate void EventHandler (string gerecht, string prijs);
    public partial class frmHoofd : Form
    {
      
        private ContrlVoorgerechten u1;
       
        delegate void MyDelegate(string[] array);

        public frmHoofd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
                    
        }

        //updating the listview control calling from the class addButton.cs
        public void UpdatingListView(string[] array)
        {
           
            if (this.lstBesteld.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.lstBesteld.Invoke(new MyDelegate(UpdatingListView), new object[] { array });
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(array[0]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(array[0]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(array[1]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(array[2]);

               //i see the string text appears correctly in the messagebox
               MessageBox.Show("mail: " +array[0] + "  count: " +array[1]+ "  price: " + array[2]);
              // lstBesteld.BeginUpdate();
               lstBesteld.Items.Add(lvi);
              // lstBesteld.EndUpdate(); 
            }

        }

        //calling the usercontrol  
        private void btVoorgerechten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              u1 = new ContrlVoorgerechten() ;
              //u1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
              u1.Width = 750;
              u1.Height = 477;
              u1.Location = new Point(430, 165);

              this.Controls.Add(u1);


I don't have any errors, but I see nothing appears in the listview control.
What I'm doing wrong?

frmHoofd frmHoofd = new frmHoofd(); - you are creating a new form in BTNclick and adding to its list view. Did you mean to add the values to an existing instance of frmHoofd?

Het stuartd, thx for your replay. Yes i'm trying to update a listview control that located in the main form (frmHoofd).

If you use another form or user control to add items in the listview in your mainform (frmHoofd), you can create a reference. In your user control add a constructor:
internal class AddButtons
{
    frmHoofd h;
    public AddButtons(frmHoofd h)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.h = h;
    }
    public void BTNclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mail= clickedbtn.Text;
        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(clickedbtn.Name); //You may need some formatting
        int count = 1;
        h.AddItem(mail, count, price);
    }
}

And then add in your frmHoofd:
public class frmHoofd : Form
{
    AddButtons ab;
    public void AddItem(string mail, int count, decimal price)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(array[0]);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(mail);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(count);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(price);
        lstBesteld.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
    private void btVoorgerechten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ab = new AddButtons(this);
        this.Controls.Add(ab);
    }
}

Btw, better use easier names for your controls. Such as Buttons, use btnAdd. This way you find your controls much easier. Also in your User control, BTNclick.. Just use btnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)...
And the last thing.. Use the correct variables. For count, use an int, for price, use a decimal. You can set the format for the currency by using the namespace System.Globalization.CultureInfo.
CultureInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("nl-NL", false);
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "";
nfi.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
nfi.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(price, nfi);

//And show the price as string
string priceDisplay = price.ToString("N", nfi); //Use N for number or C for currency. C will add the currency sign.

Also, the most importing thing, always...ALWAYS check the user input. What if the price value is empty? your app crashes. What if the user enters letters in the price value? Again.. crash..
Ps, little mistake: add this to the new instance. ab = new AddButtons(this);
